# Show Progress bar for many math calculations

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to multiply two huge int array with one another and store the result in a 3rd array. How can I show the progress if i know the length of the array in advance ?
I've no idea about how to show a progress bar properly, thus have no code to show !

Comment: Can you show us your multiplication code?

Comment: Is it a web application of windows ?

Comment: An option - show progress bar whatever way you know and see if it does not work/work worse than you want. Than you'll be able to improve this question with code sample and environment details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bars are really straightforward to work with. For example, check out my Windows form below containing a Progress Bar and a Button:

[image: Windows form wiht progress bar]

Now to increment the progress bar, I simply put the following line under my `Do Stuff` button:

```
progressBar1.Value += 10;
```

I can decrement like so:

```
progressBar1.Value -= 10;
```

The progress bar can have a value of anything between 0 and 100 by default, you can however change this by amending the `Maximum` property as `J Steen` has pointed out. All I am doing here is incrementing the value by 10 on each click. The value has both getter and setter attributes so you can check the current value to see if the progress bar has completed.

Hope this helps

Comment: You can set whatever `Maximum` you like, actually. It doesn't have to be 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
Dim x(50000), y(50000), z(50000) As Integer

Private Sub btn_Click() Handles btn.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 49999 Step 1
        z(i) = x(i) * y(i)
        bar.Value = i / 500
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint() Handles Me.Paint
    Dim r As New Random
    For i As Integer = 0 To 49999 Step 1
        x(i) = r.Next(50)
        y(i) = r.Next(50)
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```